Gadget-blocking solutions for Locally optimal cut in $5$-regular graphs
Let $G$ be a $5$-regular graph. Let $P$ be the following problem: nodes are colored with $\{R, B\}$ such that: if a node is from a color $c$, at most 2 of its neighbors have color $c$. ($P$ is sometime called Locally Optimal Cut as switching the color of a node does not increase the cut size  - number of bichromatic edges -).
Let $H$ be some induced subgraph of $G$. Let $a,b,c,d$, be 4 distinct vertices of $H$, with exactly one edge between $V(H)$ and $V(G-H)$. Can we decide the topology of $H$ such that the number of vertices of color $R$ among $a,b,c,d$ cannot take some values?
What I did: It is possible to forbid odd numbers:
Consider $H$ to be the following:
.
Suppose for a contradiction that there are 3 red vertices.

Because $a$ has already two neighbors of the same color, $1'$ and $2'$ are $B$.
$1$ and $2$ cannot both be $B$ because that would make $1'$ have 3 neighbors of the same color. The same reasoning apply for the color $R$; hence wlog $1$ is $R$ and $2$ is $B$.
$3$ cannot be $B$ as it already has $3$ $B$ neighbors. Hence it is $R$. This leaves $1$ with $3$ neighbors of the same color, a contradiction.

For this example of $H$, it is possible to have 2 nodes being $R$: a "bipartite" kind of solution where $3$ could take any color. We can also have 4 $R$: $1, 1', 2, 2'$ take $B$ and $3$ is $R$.
An other example: when $H$ is just the vertices $a,b,c,d$ with all possible edges, the only possible solution is to have 1, 2 or 3 nodes of color $R$.
Question: can we have some $H$ blocking at the same time solutions with odd numbers of $R$ and 4 or 0 $R$? Can we have some $H$ blocking solution with $2$ $R$?

Here are the smallest gadgets-blocking I found:
Blocking 1, 2, 4, 5:

Blocking 1, 3, 5:

Blocking 2, 3, 4:

Blocking 1, 5:

Blocking 2, 4:

Blocking 3:


How did you obtained these? It looks computer generated.

I modelled it with ILP and bruteforced with random graphs

can you share a few more details about it? I have never heard about it and it seems like it would be very useful for my work to know this.

Here is a gist of my code: https://gist.github.com/etiennedeg/5c3b16808f64969d60376c7b6620d56f.
Integer Linear Programming is an optimization problem with integer variables and linear constraints. $x_u = 0$ or $1$ depending on the color or vertex $u$. $(d(u)-2)(1 - x_u) \leq \sum_{v\in N(u)}x_v$ enforce that if $x_u=0$, then at least $d(u)-2$ neighbors must be $1$. $(d(u)-2)x_u \leq \sum_{v\in N(u)}(1-x_v) = d_u - \sum_{v\in N(u)}x_v$ enforce that if $x_u=1$, then at least $d(u)-2$ neighbors must be $0$.

My code is in Julia. JuMP is a library that can interface many different solvers (including some that solve non-linear problems). GLPK is a free ILP solver. You can get better performances using commercial solvers like Gurobi or CPLEX.
